# Parsing filenames with JQuery and regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing, hyperlink, filenames

So I have a couple of links:

```
<a href="#">2k01</a>
<a href="#">3a01</a>
<a href="#">5a01</a>
etc...
```

When I click on a link, I want to display a set of images associated with the text in between the  tags.  I have an images/ folder with all the images in them, and the image names are formated as "some text_2k01_some text", "some text_3a01_some text", etc.  I want to display only the images with the text inside the clicked link.  I suspect there's a solution out there using JQuery and regular expressions, but I haven't been able to find it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "some_text" is always the same for all images?

Comment: no, it changes, that was just used as an example, there could be anything before and anything after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could previously insert — as `data-*` attribute — the name of the image you want to get, like so

```
<a href="#" data-image="folder/your-image-2k01.jpg">2k01</a>
<a href="#" data-image="folder/other-image-3a01.jpg">3a01</a>
<a href="#" data-image="folder/foobar-image-5a01.jpg">5a01</a>
```

so the js would be simply

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-image]', function() {
   var $this = $(this),
       url   = $this.data('image'),
       img   = $('<img src="'+ url +'" />');

   $this.append(img);
})
```

and you won't be tied too strong to the filename format

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for this. You can use jQuery:

```
jQuery("a").click(function() {
   var linkText = jQuery(this).text();
   var filename = "sometext_" + linkText + "_sometext";
   ...
   ...code to display your images
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
     $('img').hide();
     $('img[src|="' + $(this).text() + '"]').show();
});
```

When you click a link, it will find all images on the page where the image source contains (that's what the `|=` does) whatever text was within the link and shows them. Also hides all images first, assuming you only want ones associated with the clicked link shown.